# Description item label overflows through block

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, description

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Proton Pump Inhibitor use and the Risk of Chronic Kidney Disease }
\framesubtitle{Benjamin Lazarus et al, in JAMA Intern Med. 2016;176(2)  }
\begin{block}{Result}
    \begin{description}
        \item [Hazard ratio {\textit{unadjusted analysis}}:]1.45 95\% CI: (1.11-1.90)
        \item [Hazard ratio \textit{adjusted} analysis for demographic, socioeconomic, and clinical variables:]1.5 95\% CI : (1.14-1.96)
        \item [Hazard ratio for PPI verses H2RA:] 1.35 95\% CI : 1.01-1.91  
    \end{description}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Item 2 overflows through the block. I tried to use `\\` to break it into two lines, but it ends up in error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution would be to shorten the label. The "Hazard ratio" is redudant information in every label, why not move it to e.g. to the block title?

---

I think in this case, it would be easiest to just not use a `description` environment but to to the line breaking by hand.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Proton Pump Inhibitor use and the Risk of Chronic Kidney Disease }
\framesubtitle{Benjamin Lazarus et al, in JAMA Intern Med. 2016;176(2)  }
\begin{block}{Result}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{item} Hazard ratio {\textit{unadjusted analysis}}:} 1.45 95\% CI: (1.11-1.90)\\[0.2cm]
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{item} Hazard ratio \textit{adjusted} analysis for demographic, socioeconomic, and clinical variables:} 1.5 95\% CI: (1.14-1.96)\\[0.2cm]
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{item} Hazard ratio for PPI verses H2RA:} 1.35 95\% CI: 1.01-1.91
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a second line here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Proton Pump Inhibitor use and the Risk of Chronic Kidney Disease }
\framesubtitle{Benjamin Lazarus et al, in JAMA Intern Med. 2016;176(2)}
\begin{block}{Result}
    \begin{description}
        \item [Hazard ratio \emph{unadjusted analysis}:]1.45 \SI{95}{\percent} CI: (\numrange{1.11}{1.90})
        \item [Hazard ratio \emph{adjusted} analysis for demographic, socioeconomic,]
        \item [and clinical variables:]1.5 \SI{95}{\percent} CI: (\numrange{1.14}{1.96})
        \item [Hazard ratio for PPI verses H2RA:] 1.35 \SI{95}{\percent} CI: (\numrange{1.01}{1.91})
    \end{description}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing `siunitx`